# Raspberry multiple accelerometers please help with schematic

Tags: raspberry-pi, accelerometer, pullup

I am new to electronics, and I have been playing around with Raspberry Pi 3 and an [ADXL accelerometer](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Accelerometer/ADXL345.pdf). So far, I have managed to draw data in I2C from the accelerometer. However, now I am trying to draw a schematic for a prototype with two ADXL accelerometers. I have made an attempt, but since I am new to this, I have no idea whether I am on the right track. Here's what I've put together. In particular, I am not sure about the pullup resistors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SDO pin is used for I2C addressing. There are *no* internal pullup or pulldown resistors and therefore they must be connected to a valid level.

Connect one of them to ground and the other to Vdd(io); that way you get two devices on the I2C bus at different addresses (see below). I would normally connect these through a resistor (4.7k to 47k is a common range to use).

CS must likewise be connected.

The [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf) has this to say (page 19)

> With the ALT ADDRESS pin high, the 7-bit I2C address for the device is
>   0x1D, followed by the R/W bit. This translates to 0x3A for a write and
>   0x3B for a read.
>
> An alternate I2C address of 0x53 (followed by the R/W bit) can be
>   chosen by grounding the ALT ADDRESS pin (Pin 12). This translates to
>   0xA6 for a write and 0xA7 for a read.
>
> There are no internal pull-up or pull-down resistors for any unused
>   pins; therefore, there is no known state or default state for the CS
>   or ALT ADDRESS pin if left floating or unconnected.
>
> It is required that the CS pin be connected to VDD I/O and that the
>   ALT ADDRESS pin be connected to either VDD I/O or GND when using I2C.

I2C always requires a pullup on the SDA line (it is [open drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector)), but the 4.7 ohm device you have on the schematic is not going to be close; try 2.2k as a start.

Whether you need a pullup on SCL depends on the output of the controller (but it won't hurt for one to be there); once more, you have a part identified that is simply nbot suitable - a 2.2k device would be a good starting point here as well.

Whether you need the 6.8 ohm device (R1) is debatable.

I will note that most people get asked if they have read the datasheet; as you are up-front about being new to this I am not going to make anything of it, but reading datasheets is a pre-requisite skill for virtually any task in electronics, so I would urge you to read through the datasheet and ask us where you have doubts as to the meaning of certain areas.

Updated in response to comment:

The CS pin is *required* to be pulled high for I2C operation (see the datasheet excerpt); if it is not there you can have intermittent operation (if it is a CMOS input you could conceivably destroy the device).

I also noticed you are powering from 5V; the maximum operating voltage for the ADXL345 is 3.6V; a linear 3.3V regulator to power the device would be prudent. Pulll the SDA line to thast voltage (not 5V). SCL would need a bit of thought as well.

Comment: 1) I haven't connected CS pin because many of the tutorials I found online ([e.g.](http://www.instructables.com/id/how-to-use-the-ADXL345-on-Raspberry-pi/)) only connect SDA, SCL, GND and VDD. How would that affect my setup? 2) I realized I made a mistake in the 4.7 ohm resistors. I actually meant 4.7k ohm, which is advised in the [sparkfun web site](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/i2c/i2c-at-the-hardware-level). Why do you advise to start with 2.2k ohm resistors? 3) I will make sure I know what's in the datasheet then. Thanks.